# Why can a feature-based Eclipse Application run configuration include unexpected plugins?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a feature-based product configuration and a run configuration using "Launch with: features selected below". However, when run, it includes some plug-ins which neither:

1. Are included in the feature
2. Appear when computing dependencies of the feature (it *shouldn't* depend on them, but I could have introduced a dependency accidentally)
3. Nor seem to be called by any plug-ins of the feature, based on the "Plug-in dependencies" view.

Is there a way to check why these plug-ins are included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDE is at first resolving all includes from the launch configuration's selected features. After that all dependencies from the included plugins are added. As you pointed out, PDE is going through the workspace and target for that. Another thing is that all fragments (except those not matching filters) are included when their host plugin is included. 

Take a look into this method (or run in debug ) to see where your plugins come from: `org.eclipse.pde.internal.launching.launcher.BundleLauncherHelper.getMergedBundleMap(ILaunchConfiguration, boolean)`

Answer (score 0):

PDE ignores the features configuration for launching your application within the IDE! Because of that all plug-ins in your workspace will be used.

But you can close the project which you will not launch.

Comment: That certainly doesn't seem correct, because I actually have two different feature-based configurations (for two products), and they use correct subsets of plug-ins from the workspace. "But you can close the project which you will not launch." Unfortunately, the problem happens with plug-ins not in my workspace, but in the target platform (and I can't remove them from the target platform due to http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/234167/).